# Declaring state in NGXS in a sane manner

Tags: angular, typescript, state, state-management, ngxs

I'm learning `NGXS` with the `Emitters` plugin in `Angular`, and I have some trouble understanding how to declare my state files in a managable way.

I've had success declaring a simple .state file like this:

```js
export type PageStatusCases = 'LOADING' | 'IDLE' | 'ERROR' | 'INITIALIZING';

export interface AppStateModel {
  pageStatus: PageStatusCases;
}

@State<AppStateModel>({
  name:     'AppState',
  defaults: {
    pageStatus: 'INITIALIZING'
  }
})
export class AppState {

  @Selector()
  static pageStatus(state: AppStateModel): PageStatusCases {
    return state.pageStatus;
  }

  @Receiver({type: '[Global] Page status'})
  static setPageStatus({patchState}: StateContext<AppStateModel>, {payload}: EmitterAction<PageStatusCases>): void {
    patchState({pageStatus: payload});
  }

}
```

---

Now I am trying a more complex example converting my `Service` in a `State`

In my service I have a lot of `BehaviorSubject`s keeping track of my UI's state.

```js
  title: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('');

  backClick$: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();
  primaryClick$: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();

  toolbarVisible$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(true);
  primaryVisible$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  primaryDisabled$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  primaryAutoDisabled$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  primaryIcon$: BehaviorSubject<ToolbarPrimaryIcon> = new BehaviorSubject(ToolbarPrimaryIcon.ADD);
```

I've started to convert my `BehaviorSubject`s to parts of the state, but I realized that I need to create a lot of boilerplate code.

For every `BehaviorSubject` I need to:

- Declare it in the state's model `Interface`
- Declare it's default state in the `State`
- Declare it's `@Selector` in the state "manifest"
- Declare it's `@Receiver` (`Action`) in the state
- Declare it's `@Select` in every component that needs it
- Declare it's `@Emitter` in every component that needs it, for when I want to update it

My current situation is 100+ lines of code for correctly state-managing only 7 variables, so I think I am missing something. I'm not even complaining about the amount of visual noise added.

[Clearly something is wrong](https://i.imgur.com/9WLe3kI.png)

I would like to know what am I missing and what would be a better way of declaring state in a situation like this.

I am using NGXS with the `emitters` plugin because I through it was going to reduce the amount of boilerplate but I am not gaining much at the moment.

Comment: I think this is a good question until we reached the bottom last two paragraphs where it reads like "best practices" question. It needs to be updated so that you're asking for help about a specific problem. Questions about best practices are off topic here.

Comment: I think that my code is wrong so I am asking for help from someone more expert than me

Comment: There is a lot of boilerplate code in state management. There is way more boilerplate if you use Redux. Ngxs is actually very compact compared to Redux. Based upon what I see in the question. I would say you're not doing anything *wrong*.

Answer (score 3):

There will be some boiler plate, but I think the main problem you might be seeing is having created a bunch of `@Selector` that are just accessing a single state property - the components that subscribe to the state changes don't need `@Selector` for this.

They can just subscribe to the state directly via a `@Select` binding Observable or just through a `store.select()` statement if need be. Also the image shows a bunch of `@Select` declarations with the state (also not needed).

I haven't used the `Emitters` stuff from NGXS Labs myself so I can't comment on that usage.